# ¿Extraer estructura de archivos de múltiples carpetas al primer nivel en CMD Batch?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

tal y como se ve en la imagen, necesito extraer la estructura de archivos de múltiples carpetas, uniendo las carpetas con nombre similar y sobrescribiendo si es necesario.

Normalmente uso el explorador para escribir en la búsqueda, por ejemplo buscaría "data", y cortaría todas las carpetas y las pegaría combinándolas. Pero en esta ocasión hay más variedad y subdirectorios únicos repartidos.

¿Alguna forma fácil, o difícil, de hacerlo?

Gracias desde ya.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('DIR /A:D /B') DO MOVE /Y "%A\*" ".\"

FOR /D %A IN ("D:\Carpeta pruebas\copia\*") DO MOVE "%A" "%A\..\%~NXA"

FOR /F %A IN ('DIR /A:D /B') DO MOVE /Y "%A" "%A\..\UNIQUE_FOLDER"

FOR /F %A IN ('DIR /A:D /B') DO (FOR /F %B IN ('DIR "%A" /B') DO MOVE /Y "%A\%B" "%A\..\UNIQUE_FOLDER")

FOR /F %A IN ('DIR /A:D /B') DO XCOPY "%A" "UNIQUE_FOLDER" /E /Y
```

[image: Ejemplo, estructura de directorios y archivos]

Answer (score 0):

cd C:\Ruta\Del\Directorio
cmd `tree`

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).